# Sturm-Louiville eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I am given this Sturm-Louiville problem: $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\lambda y=0$$

With boundary conditions: $y'(0) = 0, y(2) = 0$, where $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$

I am now trying to find the eigenvalues.

I tried using the general solution:

$y = A \cos(px) + B\sin(px)$, where $λ = -p^2 < 0$

I differentiated this and substituted the boundary conditions $y'(0) = 0$ to obtain that $B = 0$.

From this, I used the boundary condition $y(2) = 0$ to obtain:

$A\cos(2p) = 0.$

From this, I arrived at $p = \frac{n  \pi}{4}$.

I was hoping for some kind of confirmation if I am on the right track...I would also like some guidance of where to go from this to obtain the eigenvalues.

I tried to find the eigenvalues by simply finding $-p^2$, but I found that this was wrong.

Thank you for your time,
I appreciate any help.

Comment: There are two mistakes in your attempt:
1. For $\lambda = -p^2$, the solutions are exponential. So, you need to do $\lambda = p^2 > 0$ for the type of solutions you want.
2. $\cos \theta = 0$ when $\theta = \dfrac{\left( 2n - 1 \right) \pi}{2}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So, the values of $p$ should be $\dfrac{\left( 2n - 1 \right) \pi}{4}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Otherwise, everything seems correct.

Comment: what is the "where n=1,2,3,..." doing right after the boundary condition $y'(0)=0$, $y(2)=0$?

Comment: The question just said "with n defined as taking values n = 1, 2, 3"

Comment: And the question also names the eigenvalues as: λ(subscript n)

Comment: I also tried for =2>0, however I ended up with A = B = 0

Comment: What do you mean by $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ ???

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\lambda y=0\tag1$$

For $\lambda =0$, the general solution is $y(x)=Ax+B$,  where  $A, B$ are arbitrary constants..

The given conditions are $y'(0) = 0, y(2) = 0$ gives $A=B=0$

Hence we get $y(x)=0$, which is the trivial solution.

For $\lambda\lt 0$, say $\lambda=-p^2$

then the general solution is $y(x)=Ae^{px}+Be^{-px}$, where  $A, B$ are arbitrary constants..

The given conditions are $y'(0) = 0, y(2) = 0$ gives

$pA-pB=0\implies A-B=0$

$Ae^{2p}+Be^{-2p}=0$ which gives $A=B=0$

Hence we again get $y(x)=0$, which is the trivial solution.

So we discard these two cases and take $\lambda\gt0$.

Let $\lambda=p^2 \gt 0$

The general solution is $y(x)=A \cos(px) + B \sin(px) $, where  $A, B$ are arbitrary constants.

Now the given conditions are $y'(0) = 0, y(2) = 0$

$y'(0) = 0\implies B=0$ and $y(2) = 0\implies A\cos(2p)=0$

If we take $A=0$, then we again get the trivial equation, so we take $A \ne 0$. This gives

$~\cos(2p)=0\implies 2p=(2n-1)\frac{\pi}{2}~~~~~\text{where $~n=1,~2,~3,~\cdots~$ }$
$~\implies ~p=(2n-1)\frac{\pi}{4}~~~~~\text{where $~n=1,~2,~3,~\cdots~$ }$

So the eigen value of the given differential equation $(1)$ is $$~\lambda=p^2=~(2n-1)^2\frac{\pi^2}{16}~~~~~\text{where $~n=1,~2,~3,~\cdots~$ }~$$

and the corresponding eigen functions are $$~y(x)~=~A~\cos\left\{(2n-1)\frac{\pi}{4}~x\right\}\qquad \text{where $~n=1,~2,~3,~\cdots~~~$and $~a~$ is a constant}~.$$

---

**You can also take the following**

$~\cos(2p)=0\implies 2p=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}~~~~~\text{where $~n=0,~1,~2,~3,~\cdots~$ }$
$~\implies ~p=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{4}~~~~~\text{where $~n=0,~1,~2,~3,~\cdots~$ }$

So the eigen value of the given differential equation $(1)$ is $$~\lambda=p^2=~(2n+1)^2\frac{\pi^2}{16}~~~~~\text{where $~n=0,~1,~2,~3,~\cdots~$ }~$$

and the corresponding eigen functions are $$~y(x)~=~A~\cos\left\{(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{4}~x\right\}\qquad \text{where $~n=0,~1,~2,~3,~\cdots~~~$and $~a~$ is a constant}~.$$

**Note:** In both the two cases the values of $~\lambda~$ are same, in the first one $~n~$ does not take the value $~0~$, and in the second case it takes.

Comment: I agree with =2>0, but I don't think those eigenvalues and eigenfunction is correct. ?

Comment: Please give the full explanation, why you think so ? And also where I am wrong ?

Comment: Do you think the eigenvalues are $(2n+1)^2\frac{\pi^2}{16}$ and the corresponding eigenfunctions are $\cos\{(2n+1)\frac{\pi }{4}x\}$   $\qquad \text{where}\qquad n=0,1,2,3,. . .$

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic equation is

$$z^2+\lambda=0$$ and there are three regimes:

- $\lambda > 0\to y=A\cos\sqrt\lambda x+B\sin\sqrt\lambda x$,
- $\lambda = 0\to y=Ax+B$,
- $\lambda < 0\to y=Ae^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}+Be^{-\sqrt{-\lambda }x}$.

By plugging the given limit conditions (for generality, $l=2$),

- $\lambda > 0\to 0=B,0=A\cos \sqrt\lambda l+B\sin \sqrt\lambda l$,
- $\lambda = 0\to 0=A,0=Al+B$,
- $\lambda < 0\to 0=A-B,0=Ae^{\sqrt{-\lambda}l}+Be^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}l}$

or

- $\lambda > 0\to \cos \sqrt\lambda l=0$,
- $\lambda = 0\to 1=0$, which is not possible,
- $\lambda < 0\to \cosh\sqrt{-\lambda}l=0$, which is not possible.

So for $\lambda>0$,

$$\sqrt\lambda l=(2k+1)\frac\pi2$$ or $$\lambda=\frac{(2k+1)^2\pi^2}{4l^2}$$ must hold for non-trivial solutions to exist.

The first Eigenfunctions:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Any eigenfunction must be a non-zero constant multiple of the solution of
$$
          y''+\lambda y =0,\;\; y(0)=1,\; y'(0)=0,
$$
which has unique solution
$$
        y(x) = \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x).
$$
Then, in order to satisfy $y(2)=0$, $\lambda$ must satisfy
$$
           \cos(2\sqrt{\lambda})=0.
$$
 The general solution is
$$
                2\sqrt{\lambda} = (n+1/2)\pi ,\;\; n=0,1,2,3,\cdots, \\
                \lambda = (n+1/2)^2\pi^2/4,\;\;\; n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
The corresponding eigenfunctions are
$$
           y_n(x) = \cos((n+1/2)\pi x/2),\;\; n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$

Comment: This is absolutely wrong. Because given conditions are $~y'(0) = 0, ~y(2) = 0~$, not what you taken.

Comment: @nmasanta : You are jumping to conclusions. If you have a non-trivial solution of the equation with $y'(0)=0$, then $y$ is either identically zero or $y(0)\ne 0$ and the solution can be normalized so that $y(0)=1$. And since you care only about the non-trivial solutions, then you can normalize so that $y(0)=1$. Nothing is lost in do that. That's all I'm saying. Then you can look for solutions of those which also satisfy $y'(2)=0$, and that gives the eigenvalue equation, which becomes an equation for the zeros of an everywhere convergent power series in $\lambda$.

Comment: Why you are taking more conditions, while you had been provided enough conditions to solve the problem ?@DisintegratingByParts

Comment: @nmasanta : Because, when you add the extra normalization, then you can show that the value of $y'(2)$ or $y(2)$, etc., will be an everywhere convergent power series in $\lambda$. And that gives rid of a lot of annoying special cases because they become limiting cases of a power series. And nothing is lost in doing so because you can always normalize the solution by adding an extra condition, such as what I've done. And I've explained why that works and does not add or take away from the solutions.

Comment: @nmasanta : I'm sorry, I did not notice I changed y(2)=0 to y'(2)=0 in your problem. I fixed that part now.

Comment: Now it seems ok.